# SQL select where more than 1 junction

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a many to many relationship between books and authors.

How can I get all books that have more than one author? (In the example database below this would be 0)

books table:

```
+--------+------------------+
| BookId |       Book       |
+--------+------------------+
|      1 | Wizard of Oz     |
|      2 | Huckleberry Finn |
+--------+------------------+
```

author table:

```
+----------+------------------+
| AuthorId |      Author      |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 | Mark Twain       |
|        2 | Lyman Frank Baum |
+----------+------------------+
```

junction table:

```
+--------+----------+
| BookId | AuthorId |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        2 |
|      2 |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use group by an having count

```
select books.* from  books
inner join  junction  on books.id  = junction.bookid 
group by bookId 
having count(distinct AuthorId ) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

use `distinct`     count()

```
  select * from books where BookId
in (  select BookId from junction_table
    group by BookId
    having count(distinct AuthorId)>=2
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

CTE (Common Table Expression) could be used here (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

First name the CTE, specify the inner query i.e. get all the book names that have more than one author, and then use an outer query to pull the details of books returned by the CTE. The advantage is CTE is modular and readable.

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
  SELECT Bookid,COUNT(DISTINCT AuthorID) AS No_Of_Authors
  FROM
  Junction
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AuthorID)>1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE  C JOIN Book B
ON
C.Bookid=B.Bookid
```

Comment: Just dumping code is not an answer. Explain why your code is preferred over that of the three other answer given. This way we all can learn from it. (End of Low-Quality Review).

Answer (score 0):

Please try if following does what you expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT b, COUNT(b) as authors
    FROM j
    GROUP BY 1
) cnt
WHERE cnt.authors > 1
```